# PHP is_numeric vs ~(~(float)$value) performance and function

Tags: php, floating-point, bitwise-operators

Recently I wanted to search an array for numeric values (ints, doubles, and numbers with exponent notation) as quickly as possible.

I initially used 'is_numeric()' as we often use that as our goto for checking but I wanted to see if I could put in something faster.

I noticed that if I cast to float then as long as the value is numeric PHP will produce a value other than zero. So using the bitwise operators I can do a logical NOT zero within the if statement surrounding the search.

```
if (~(~(float)$value)) {
// add to result array
}
```

After initial testing I found things seemed to speed up by 2 whole seconds with a moderately sized array of numerics and non numerics. However this was little more than a simple unit test.

Does anyone have experience of performance of casting as a float vs is_numeric? I know they're probably not 100% functionally equivalent (I think the cast to float would convert hexadecimal) but for my purposes I'm only going to be casting ints, doubles and numbers with an exponent notation. Is this a performance gain over is_numeric() or have I imagined this?

Comment: After doing more research and with help from the official answer I've realized they're really not functionally equivalent. So the performance gain is probably real but at the cost of much less rigor in checking of the value. Probably only to be used with guaranteed inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

warning!
isnumeric () is not just a whim, I am attaching a small piece of code that shows you the error that your conversion type makes. in many attacks on php there are strings that can be both numbers and squeaks where the attackers inject bad code.

**code:**

```
<?php
$a="1809809808908099878758765<?php echo \"I powned you\"; ?>";
echo is_numeric($a)?"yes":"no";   // out no
echo "\n";
echo (~(~(float)$a))?"Yes":"No";  // out Yes
```

if you do it that way you could gain performance but depending on what you have to do you could open a hole in security!

Comment: Thank you! I had not tested that at all.